# Embedding $\mathbb{CP}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{4n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-space

I'm looking for a generalization of the map of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a sphere.
Are there any such (preferably canonical) embeddings of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{4n-1}$? (And is $4n-1$ the correct dimension to be asking this question in?)

Comment: For your second question, yes, every smooth compact complex manifold of complex dimension $n$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{4n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my second question is definitely a little vague, but it was more along the lines of: "it doesn't have to be in $\mathbb{R}^{4n-1}$ as long as the embedding is simple/natural and agrees with the sphere mapping for $n = 1$".